# can you load videos in flutter through an api?

Tags: flutter, dart, caching, video, preloading

I found this article to upload videos but it already has the urls of the videos written.
I need to pass the videos through an api.
Any ideas??
https://medium.com/@sanjeevmadhav03/preloading-videos-in-flutter-4b65cf0681c6

Comment: Usually it depends on the API to know if the video is playable in your system... Does your API give back a URL link to some MP4 video (starting with `https` and ending `.mp4`)?

Comment: yes, the problem is that in the example of the link that passes, this static,
but I need to know from the example how to add it by API
In state.dart

Comment: I'm not understanding properly... You know how to get the URL  (as String) but problem is giving to the video player function? If yes... Make the `urls` array as variable not const, then you can change the URLs inside. Maybe test by making your `urls[0] = your_URL_string_here;` then to play it you call `_playControllerAtIndex( 0 );` but you might need to do a `await _initializeControllerAtIndex(0);` before doing the play...

Comment: but in the code it does not let me replace it with an await or a method and change the String of the URLs:

Comment: urls: const [
'https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/videos/butterfly.mp4#1',
'https://assets.mixkit.co/videos/preview/mixkit-young-mother-with-her-little-daughter-decorating-a-christmas-tree-39745-large.mp4',
'https://assets.mixkit.co/videos/preview/mixkit-mother-with-her-little-daughter-eating-a-marshmallow-in-nature-39764-large.mp4',
'https://assets.mixkit.co/videos/preview/mixkit-girl-in-neon-sign-1232-large.mp4',
],

Comment: ERROR: 
error: Factory bodies can't use 'async', 'async*', or 'sync*'. (non_sync_factory at [] lib\bloc\preload_state.dart:9)

Answer (score 0):

Check if your api endpoint Supports upload of binary files. If it does, check if you're given url of the location of the video